# ClientId on GenerateAccessToken not working and no definition for ClientSecret

Tags: apigee

I'm trying to define specific ClientId and ClientSecret variables for policy OauthV2 for GenerateAccessToken but the ClientId it doesn't seem to take effect and the ClientSecret doesnt seem to event exist as a possibility. what are my configuration options in here?

**Optional Answer**

extract the variables and then reassign them in the right place expected by the policy.

Comment: Im using apigee the proxy service

Answer (score 0):

Your optional answer is mostly correct.  After extracting the variables, you could store them in a Key-Value Map and then look up the info from the Map and use it.

Answer (score 0):

By default the OAuthV2 policy expects to see the client ID and client secret separated by a colon and encoded as a base64 string in the Authorization header, as in:

Authorization: Basic

Alternately you can specify those values anywhere in your request (headers, query params, payload) and provide them to the OAuthV2 policy by creating an Authorization header using the BasicAuthentication policy (http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/basic-authentication-policy) and associating it with the request prior to invoking the OAuthV2 policy.  In the BasicAuthentication policy specify the client ID in the "User" element and the client secret in the "Password" element.